# Joomla 3.2 Increase the upload_max_filesiz

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I am trying to download this template on Joomla 3.2 extension manger :
http://scriptmafia.org/templates/115622-yt-moustache-yootheme-for-joomla-25-32.html
but every time I upload it, it gives me this error:

> There was an error uploading this file to the server.

I have read articles about "increase the upload max size in the php.ini file".
I have tried to find this file in the administrator files section in Joomla, but it is "not found".

So how can I fix this problem?  It has not happened for this template only, it has happened for several.  So I am almost sure it is due to the upload size.

Comment: can you just post the error you got please?

Comment: ==> php.ini is not a joomla file, it is a file which contains settings of your PHP installation and you can find this file at installation directory of PHP, in your system.



==> This error may be because of permission setting of your "joomla_installatio/tmp" directory.

Comment: can you explain in more details please how i open php on my machine and edit its code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using XAMPP , php.ini file will be located in c:\XAMPP\php folder. Find the file and increase file upload size there.
If you are using WAMP, You can find ini file in /wamp/bin/php directory.
The location may vary from one OS to another.
You can follow this link:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/

Comment: I download joomla on windows IIS

Answer (score 4):

Edit your **php.ini** and increase *upload_max_filesize* and *post_max_size*; then restart your web server.

If you don't know where is your php.ini, create a php file to discover: `echo php_ini_loaded_file();`

The returned path is where your php.ini is located.

**EDIT**

Well, seems like you have a permission error and not size limit. Try to change permissions of the **temp** Joomla folder (you can see/configure it on Global Configuration > System).

Comment: i cant find this file in my joomla administrator folder

Comment: did you even read the full question. Its clearly written that he has already read about it

Comment: I've changed my answer. :)

Comment: sorry i still not have good experience in php where i create this file and where exactly i put it and send me full code please

Comment: yoy mean like this : 
<?php
$inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();

if ($inipath) {
    echo 'Loaded php.ini: ' . $inipath;
} else {
    echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
}
?>

Comment: Yep, this code works. You should run this script and then you will know where is your php.ini. Save as filename.php on your "www" diretory and runs on your browser. (e.g.: http://localhost/filename.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can call in your script ini_set function and change values, which have been stored in php.ini (any changes has affected only for current script, but not for global settings)

```
ini_set('post_max_size', "%value in MiB for example 16M%")
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', "%value in MiB for example 16M%")
```

You can read more about it at [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't resolve the PHP limitation easily, an alternative is to FTP the installation file to the /tmp folder and in Extension Manager -> Install, use the "Install from Directory" option instead.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue for the longest time, none of the answers helped. Found that if you are using GoDaddy, and go to your CPanel, scroll down to Software, then choose PHP version, switch to PHP Options, there you can change your upload file size. Hope this helps, took me forever to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Some people might be having a issue with the memory allocation portion of php.ini file "memory_limit" the default for me was 128mb and i was attempting to upload nearly 300mb and it hit that roadblock. After changing the default value to 512mb and restarting the server i was able to get past this limit.

Answer (score 0):

How to change `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in a local installation of Joomla 3 in XAMPP

1. You can check the php setting in two places – site’s backend under system information – go to php information. Or on browser go to localhost and click on phpinfo. You’ll find the post and upload part under “Core” heading.
2. Go to `c:\xampp\php\`
3. Find the file `php.ini`
4. Open `php.ini` in notepad
5. Find `post_max_size` and change value to `20M`
6. Find `upload_max_filesize` and change value to `20M`
7. Save the file
8. Logout out of your site backend.
9. Turn off apache and mysql on xampp and quit
10. Restart xampp as administrator
11. Turn on apache and mysql
12. Open browser and go to localhost
13. Open phpinfo and search for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`.
14. Confirm that changes are registered.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen with the following `suhosin` setting:

```
suhosin.upload.disallow_binary = On
```

Setting it to `off` temporarily allows you to upload zip files

Answer (score 0):

If you use CPanel, search for PHP version (in the Software section) and click on it, then click on 'switch to PHP Options', the options will display then look for 'upload_max_filesize' and click on the value to change it. Do the same for 'post_max_size'.